# Cannot loop through links with selenium in Python

Tags: python

Heres the problem. I have a list of links i have created and i want selenium to visit them.I used a for loop for this, but after the first link, it gives me this error:

```
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

links = ['https://www.youtube.com','https://www.google.com']

driver = webdriver.Chrome(R'C:\Users\a1234\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.close()
```

Also,since im using sublime text i have to use `R` for raw strings so that is not a mistake. But anyways thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

close your browser after the for loop has completed

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

links = ['https://www.youtube.com','https://www.google.com']

driver = webdriver.Chrome(R'C:\Users\a1234\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')

for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```